# Font-Awesome shows random squares only in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, font-awesome, mozilla

So, I have been using HTML, CSS, Bootstrap and FontAwesome (the last versions). I was using Firefox Web Developer's Editition and everything was fine than I closed my browser with my code saved and a few hours later I opened the same code in the same browser however my font awesome icons was seen as squares.

I tried it with other browsers including Firefox (not-developer editition), Chrome and Edge and I was able to see my icons there. But in this browser the code suddenly stoped working.

Here is my local path for FA; C:\HTML\futuredeneme\fa\css\all.css
Here is my local path for HTML; C:\HTML\futuredeneme\home.html
Here is my link;     `<link rel="stylesheet" href="fa\css\all.css">`

Here is an example of my code:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav justify-content-end text-center">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="#"><i class="fas fa-home fa-lg"></i><br>Anasayfa</a>
           </li>
         </ul>
```

Comment: `fa` --> `fas` . *The fa prefix has been deprecated in version 5. The new default is the fas solid style and the fab style for brands.* https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use

Comment: I am aware of it but that doesn't work either

Comment: This sounds like a browser cache issue _ I speak from experience because I use Firefox Developer Edition too _ Once in a while I've suffered similar to what you have described _ Unfortunately_ cache cleaner attachments don't seem to work either _ Sometimes _in extremis_ I've cold-booted my computer to clear the cache